# Byte to int conversion after serial communication between ardino and android

Tags: java, android, arrays, arduino, data-conversion

I'm transfering positive integers between 0 and 10000 between my Android phone and my Arduino. 
Since the serial sends a byte array, I've to convert the sent byte array back to an integer.

But everything I tried does either throw a

> java.nio.BufferUnderflowException

or returns a wrong value (my Arduino sends 150, I get -106)!

I tried it with ByteBuffer:

```
@Override
public void onNewData(final byte[] data) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.append("Read: " + ByteBuffer.allocate(4).put(data).getInt());
        }
    });
}
```

And I tried it for values smaller 255 (the 150 I mentionend before):

```
@Override
public void onNewData(final byte[] data) {
   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editText.append("Read: " + new Byte(data[0]).intValue());
        }
    });
}
```

The Arduino sends the following:

```
uint16_t iSend = 150;

void loop() {
  Serial.write(iSend);

  delay(1000);
}
```

And my android phone reads the following:

```
D/SerialInputOutputManager: Read data len=1
D/UsbRequestJNI: init
D/UsbRequestJNI: close
D/UsbRequestJNI: init
I/System.out: 0x00000000 96
```

Did anyone solve a similar problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might also have a problem with [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), if you still have issues after using `ByteBuffer` correctly post the byte array you get from Arduino.

Comment: You mean, i'd have to flip my byte to get the right value?

Comment: Yes, (not the byte, the byte array, the bytes themselves are definitely fine), or call `order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)` on your `ByteBuffer` (it's BigEndian by default).

Comment: You should start telling us how many bytes are sent for each number.

Comment: And give an example where you give hexadecimal representation of the sent bytes and then of the received bytes. Only then you see right away if they are swapped.

Comment: Everything looks right, Hex(96) is Decimal(150)?! Just the bytebuffer doesn't convert it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Serial.write(iSend);` - According to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write) this method accepts a byte, so only a single byte will be sent by calling this method. It is clear that this happens from the length of the data array. (`data len=1`).

You then try to read an integer from the bytebuffer, this requires 4 bytes but the `data` input will only ever supply a single byte.

Simply put the only valid call for your input is `ByteBuffer.wrap(data).get()`.

Finally regarding `(my Arduino sends 150, I get -106)!`, the number is stored as `uint16_t` on the arduino. This is an unsigned number while java only deals with signed numbers. This means the byte is interpreted as a signed byte when it arrives on the java side. `0x96` is `-106` when interpreted as a signed byte.

To interpret an unsigned byte in java, you can use the following code to coerce it to a short:

```
short readAsUnsigned(byte b) {
    short tmp = (short) b;
    if (tmp < 0) {
        tmp += 256;
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

Printing `readAsUnsigned(ByteBuffer.wrap(data).get())` should then print `150`

Comment: So I can't write number > 255?

Comment: You will need to use the `Serial.write(buf, len)` method to write more than 1 byte. You also need to be careful about endian-ness in that case.

Comment: Well, and how do I tell java then thats an unsigned byte?

Comment: Added a method to read the correct unsigned number to the answer. `byte` in java can strictly hold `-128` to `127`, so it converts to a `short` to hold the higher values.

Comment: And if I want this for e.g. 5500, I'll have to use 2^16 instead of 256?

Comment: If you want to write `5500`, then you need to multiple bytes and just read a `short`.

Answer (score 0):

> (my Arduino sends 150, I get -106)!

This is expected behavior. Java doesn't support unsigned bytes.  -106 is a signed byte corresponding to 150 as unsigned. The normal recourse  is  something like:

```
byte b = 0x96; // b has decimal value -106
int x = b & 0xff; // x now has int value 150.
```

Now you can manipulate `x` as a positive value.